# photo property of TeleDartMessage class have length 4

Tags: dart, telegram-bot

#### The question

I'm trying to get photos that was sent to my telegram bot by user and store them on remote server.
To do this I want to get photos from `photo` property of `TeleDartMessage` that have return type `List<PhotoSize>?`.
But for some reason the `photo.length` is always equals 4, no mater if user send 1 or 5 photos.
The questions are:

- how to get all photos that user sent to bot?
- why the length is always 4, no matter if user sent 1 or 5 photos?

Thanks!

#### The snippet to reproduce the behavior:

```dart
teledart.telegram.sendMessage(
      message.chat.id,
      'add photos',
    );
final messageSubscription = teledart.onMessage().listen((_) {});
messageSubscription.onData((data) async {
   print(data.photo!.length);
}
```

#### Expected behavior

For my opinion, the photos property has to return the amount of objects (photos) that was sent by user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So the right answer is that `photo` property of `TeleDartMessage` contains four different photo's dimension (first is the smallest and most worse quality, and the last is the biggest and best image quality).

And the code snippet from above:

```dart
// ...
messageSubscription.onData((data) async {
   print(data.photo!.length);
}
```

will be triggered every time when you send photo to bot, until the subscription will be canceled.